# Can't find google-translate package from melpa

Tags: package

Why can't my emacs find the google-translate package from melpa ?
I have trried

```
(use-package google-translate :ensure t)
```

And it doesn't find it, also `M-x install-package` does provide a `google-translate` entry with tab completion, but it still doesn't find the package.

Comment: What's the result of `M-x package-install google-translate` exactly? Maybe your package archives is outdated, if so, try `M-x package-refresh-contents` first.

Comment: Oh thanks it was just that ! I thought package list was refreshed after each start but thanks not.

Comment: @Nicolas That's correct. The refresh is automatic whenever you do a fresh `M-x package-list-packages`. You should not need to do the refresh manually.

Comment: @Nicolas Or looks like that you never list the packages and usually just do `M-x package-install`.

Comment: Kind of, I use the `use-package` package with `ensure: t` option.

Comment: In that case, it might be useful to open an issue on the use-package github, listing steps how to recereate with problem in an emacs -Q session with just use-package loaded.

Comment: @xuchunyang Can you write your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me as well from time to time, the cause is melpa keeps only latest version of packages, so it is safe to always update package archive with `M-x package-refresh-contents` or `M-x list-packages` before installing package from melpa, of course, this is time-consuming and inconvenient.

---

Here is a rough programmatic solution that I can think of at this moment, I guess both `M-x package-install some-package` and `(use-package some-package :ensure t)` should work even when `some-package`'s archive is outdated.

```el
(defun package-install-ensure-melpa (orig-fun &rest args)
  (condition-case nil
      (apply orig-fun args)
    (error
     (progn (package-refresh-contents)
            (apply orig-fun args)))))

(advice-add 'package-install :around #'package-install-ensure-melpa)
```